# Rotate taken photo in Windows Store Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have created a Universal App which has a capability of taking photos which I do like this:

```
var imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                "photo.jpg",
                CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

await _captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);

var photo = new  BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
```

When I then open the photo I see it rotated by 90 degrees (only images that are taken with the phone in portrate mode!). How can I rotate it back so that it's all displayed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

With [BitmapTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform) you can do some simple transformations to bitmap images. [Here](http://books.google.ch/books?id=Dd9PAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA346&lpg=PA346&dq=bitmaptransform+rotate+image+c%23&source=bl&ots=fKje4tmb_9&sig=O7k6zoV6HaSj690omijBVmGj87w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W5j1U9qqI829PZ3ggOAB&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=bitmaptransform%20rotate%20image%20c%23&f=false) is a sample of how a bitmap is rotated by 90 degrees.

HTH